# Remove empty divs with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can i remove all the .sidebar_szuro_div divs, where the .filters_container div inside them is empty?

I tryed finding these divs, but there are many of them, not just one, so i think, maybe i will need a loop for this, or the each() function?

Can i do this only with jquery, or i have to modify my sql select? (i prefer jquery solution for this, because i think thats more easy.)

Thank you for you help.

```html
<form name="szures_form" method="get">
  <div class="sidebar_szurok_box">
    <div class="sidebar_szuro_div">
      <h4><span class="sidebar_title">Alkalmazási hely szerint</span></h4>
      <div class="filters_container">
        <div class="checkbox padding_left_10 filter_div">
          <label>
                <input type="checkbox"  name="f[8][]" value="25">
                Padlószerkezetnél is alkalmazható</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="sidebar_szuro_div">
      <h4><span class="sidebar_title">Felület</span></h4>
      <div class="filters_container">
        <div class="checkbox padding_left_10 filter_div">
          <label>
                <input type="checkbox"  name="f[6][]" value="39">
                Függőleges és vízszintes felületen is</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="sidebar_szuro_div">
      <h4><span class="sidebar_title">Fűtésrendszer szerint</span></h4>
      <div class="filters_container"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="sidebar_szuro_div">
      <h4><span class="sidebar_title">Kiszerelés</span></h4>
      <div class="filters_container">
        <div class="checkbox padding_left_10 filter_div">
          <label>
                <input type="checkbox"  name="f[11][]" value="40">
                310 ml</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="sidebar_szuro_div">
      <h4><span class="sidebar_title">Páraáteresztő képesség</span></h4>
      <div class="filters_container"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="sidebar_szuro_div">
      <h4><span class="sidebar_title">Szín</span></h4>
      <div class="filters_container"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="sidebar_szuro_div">
      <h4><span class="sidebar_title">Vakolat maximum szemcsemérete</span></h4>
      <div class="filters_container"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="sidebar_szuro_div">
      <h4><span class="sidebar_title">Vakolat tulajdonság szerint</span></h4>
      <div class="filters_container"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="sidebar_szuro_div">
    <h4><span class="sidebar_title">Raklap bontható</span></h4>
    <div class="filters_container">
      <div class="checkbox padding_left_10 filter_div">
        <label>
              <input  type="checkbox" name="termek_csak_egesz_raklap" value="0">
              Igen</label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button type="submit" name="filter_submit_btn" class="btn LoginButton"><i class="fa fa-th-list" aria-hidden="true"></i> Szűrés </button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: simple use this oen line scrips - $(".filters_container:empty").closest(".sidebar_szuro_div").remove();

Comment: @ac4355211 see the updated asnwer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by using css also

```
div.filters_container:empty {
   display: none;
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:empty

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(".sidebar_szuro_div .filters_container").each(function() {
   if( $(this).text().trim() === '' )
        $(this).closest(".sidebar_szuro_div").remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="szures_form" method="get">
  <div class="sidebar_szurok_box">
    <div class="sidebar_szuro_div">
      <h4><span class="sidebar_title">Alkalmazási hely szerint</span></h4>
      <div class="filters_container">
        <div class="checkbox padding_left_10 filter_div">
          <label>
            <input type="checkbox"  name="f[8][]" value="25">
            Padlószerkezetnél is alkalmazható</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="sidebar_szuro_div">
      <h4><span class="sidebar_title">Felület</span></h4>
      <div class="filters_container">
        <div class="checkbox padding_left_10 filter_div">
          <label>
            <input type="checkbox"  name="f[6][]" value="39">
            Függőleges és vízszintes felületen is</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="sidebar_szuro_div">
      <h4><span class="sidebar_title">Fűtésrendszer szerint</span></h4>
      <div class="filters_container"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="sidebar_szuro_div">
      <h4><span class="sidebar_title">Kiszerelés</span></h4>
      <div class="filters_container">
        <div class="checkbox padding_left_10 filter_div">
          <label>
            <input type="checkbox"  name="f[11][]" value="40">
            310 ml</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="sidebar_szuro_div">
      <h4><span class="sidebar_title">Páraáteresztő képesség</span></h4>
      <div class="filters_container"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="sidebar_szuro_div">
      <h4><span class="sidebar_title">Szín</span></h4>
      <div class="filters_container"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="sidebar_szuro_div">
      <h4><span class="sidebar_title">Vakolat maximum szemcsemérete</span></h4>
      <div class="filters_container"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="sidebar_szuro_div">
      <h4><span class="sidebar_title">Vakolat tulajdonság szerint</span></h4>
      <div class="filters_container"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="sidebar_szuro_div">
    <h4><span class="sidebar_title">Raklap bontható</span></h4>
    <div class="filters_container">
      <div class="checkbox padding_left_10 filter_div">
        <label>
          <input  type="checkbox" name="termek_csak_egesz_raklap" value="0">
          Igen</label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button type="submit" name="filter_submit_btn" class="btn LoginButton"><i class="fa fa-th-list" aria-hidden="true"></i> Szűrés </button>
  </div>
</form>
```

```
$(".sidebar_szuro_div .filters_container").each(function() {
   if( $(this).text().trim() === '' )
        $(this).closest(".sidebar_szuro_div").remove();
});
```

Answer (score -1):

**You can use as below in 1 line** with the use of `:empty` and `remove()`

```js
$('.sidebar_szuro_div').find('.filters_container:empty').parents('.sidebar_szuro_div').remove()
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="szures_form" method="get">
  <div class="sidebar_szurok_box">
    <div class="sidebar_szuro_div">
      <h4><span class="sidebar_title">Alkalmazási hely szerint</span></h4>
      <div class="filters_container">
        <div class="checkbox padding_left_10 filter_div">
          <label>
            <input type="checkbox"  name="f[8][]" value="25">
            Padlószerkezetnél is alkalmazható</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="sidebar_szuro_div">
      <h4><span class="sidebar_title">Felület</span></h4>
      <div class="filters_container">
        <div class="checkbox padding_left_10 filter_div">
          <label>
            <input type="checkbox"  name="f[6][]" value="39">
            Függőleges és vízszintes felületen is</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="sidebar_szuro_div">
      <h4><span class="sidebar_title">Fűtésrendszer szerint</span></h4>
      <div class="filters_container"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="sidebar_szuro_div">
      <h4><span class="sidebar_title">Kiszerelés</span></h4>
      <div class="filters_container">
        <div class="checkbox padding_left_10 filter_div">
          <label>
            <input type="checkbox"  name="f[11][]" value="40">
            310 ml</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="sidebar_szuro_div">
      <h4><span class="sidebar_title">Páraáteresztő képesség</span></h4>
      <div class="filters_container"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="sidebar_szuro_div">
      <h4><span class="sidebar_title">Szín</span></h4>
      <div class="filters_container"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="sidebar_szuro_div">
      <h4><span class="sidebar_title">Vakolat maximum szemcsemérete</span></h4>
      <div class="filters_container"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="sidebar_szuro_div">
      <h4><span class="sidebar_title">Vakolat tulajdonság szerint</span></h4>
      <div class="filters_container"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="sidebar_szuro_div">
    <h4><span class="sidebar_title">Raklap bontható</span></h4>
    <div class="filters_container">
      <div class="checkbox padding_left_10 filter_div">
        <label>
          <input  type="checkbox" name="termek_csak_egesz_raklap" value="0">
          Igen</label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button type="submit" name="filter_submit_btn" class="btn LoginButton"><i class="fa fa-th-list" aria-hidden="true"></i> Szűrés </button>
  </div>
</form>
```